# A Windows Scheduled Task is running a Python script every day. How do I see the Python shell when this runs?

Tags: python, bash

The script is started via the Actions tab:

C:\users\etc\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\python.exe C:\program\main.py -e

This occurs every day at the same time.

The problem is that this task (which usually lasts 2 hours) is now stopping prematurely after ~1 hour, in different places of the script, usually when trying to establish a connection to a database.

When I run this python script from Git Bash, I haven't experienced any issues so far. I would like to watch it run in a shell when the scheduled task kicks in, but how would I be able to do that?

I have been using the Windows get-content command to watch the logs file as it runs but it's not that accurate.

Any ideas ?